# The development server returned response error code: 500 react-native why this error can any one tell me

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
at resolveDependencies (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
at processModule (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
at async addDependency (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
at async Promise.all (index 8)
at async processModule (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:198:5)
at async addDependency (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
at async Promise.all (index 6)
at async processModule (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:198:5)
at async addDependency (G:\React-Native\Native\chatmat\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
at async Promise.all (index 2)[Please see this images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR8hW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please show your query.

The error says it is not able to get parameter like

`something`.reduce , so it is not getting that something- it can either be  null or undefined currently. You can put `something?`.reduce to check for null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your reduce is undefined or not getting it's value. Please check that. Also check the dependency you have used in this screen try to uninstall and then install it.